# UbiquityIdentityToken Returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I'm trying to get the `ubiquityIdentityToken` but I always get a null value even after signing in to iCloud. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I also tried signing in and signing out but i still get no value.

Since i'm already asking about the said token, I would like to add a follow up question:
Is the ubiquity token different for every device even if the same user is signed in? Let's say I have 2 devices. I have one iCloud account. I signed in to both of my devices. Will i get the same token for both devices because i'm using the same account? or will i get different ones because it's signed in to different devices?

I hope someone can help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the Documents & Data setting? You will get nil for the token if that is not enabled.

As far as I know, you cannot assume that you will get the same token on two devices.

Comment: Yup. it's already enabled. I see. so have you tried checking it before? That's what I want to know that's why i'm trying to get the token myself. Sadly, I don't get any value. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: In that case, I suspect your app is not setup properly for iCloud. Did you create a provisioning profile for your app bundle with iCloud enabled, and build with that? Did you add iCloud to the app entitlements?

Comment: I guess you're right. I don't have the proper entitlements. Thanks. I was able to make it work. I'll just accept your comment as the answer. Thank you!!!